# How to capture UDP traffic so it can be piped to grep

Tags: udp, netcat, tshark, socat, statsd

I'm trying to capture UDP traffic which is being sent as StatsD metrics (on port 8125).

The most simple approach I tried is to run `nc -ul 8125` which prints the metrics to the terminal...but they are not newline separated. Additionally, piping the output to grep doesn't display anything.

The next approach I tried was `socat - udp-listen:8125` which gives similar results to netcat.

However, when I pass in the -v flat *and* pipe stderr to stdout, (`socat -v - udp-listen:8125  2> &1 | grep ...`) then I get vaguely decent results but there's lots of additional unwanted output.

I also tried tshark, `tshark -l -f "port 8125" -i ln0 -E separator=, -Tfields -e data` but this prints the output as hexadecimal...not ascii. I can pass in the -x flag, which prints both the hex and the ascii side by side. Not really what I want, and not very grep friendly. I've also tried a bunch of other tshark options, but nothing was able to simply print the UDP metrics.

I have seen some examples where somebody doing something similar is pipling output like `| while read output; do echo $output; done;` However, I've not had any success with that approach and I'm not really a unix guy so I'm struggling to come up with a solution.

After all, it doesn't seem like such a uncommon task, and `nc -ul 8125` is *almost* there....

To give more context...the code doing the sending looks like this:

```
var udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Connect("127.1", 9999);
while (true)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hi");
    udpClient.Send(bytes, bytes.Length);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

the desired output would look like

```
hi
hi
hi
...
```

whereas `nc -ul 9999` outputs `hihihihihi....`

Comment: Maybe the `-e text` option could help ? [See How do I extract all the "data" sections?](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/16268/how-do-i-extract-all-the-data-sections). Also have a look at the `-z` option.

Comment: No dice. With -e text, for whatever reason the output is just "Timestamps". Going by the comments in the link you sent, this option might not work well with UDP. I have tried using -z"follow,udp,ascii,0" and other such things without success.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what the desired output should look like. Can you give an example ?

Comment: I've updated the question to give more context and desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
socat -u UDP-RECVFROM:8125,fork SYSTEM:"sed G"
```

This seems to work although there is a bit more than just new line attached. Also maybe this thread can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458951/how-can-i-add-message-delimiters-to-a-udp-stream-socat-is-piping

To expand why `sed G` works... 
**sed** has two "spaces" pattern space and hold space. `sed G` basically takes what's in the **pattern** space and adds newline to it. In this case the **pattern** space is empty so it effectively just adds a new line.

Comment: somewhat cryptic but nice work!